# NumPy Inline 2D Array Manipulation

Tags: python, numpy

How can we do the following operation in one line only in numpy?

```
medians = np.median(x, axis=0)

for i in range(0, len(x)): # transforming input data to binary values
    for j in range(0, len(x[i])):
        x[i][j] = 1 if x[i][j] <= medians[j] else 2
```

What it does is to transform this feature vector into binary values based on the values of the median for that dimension of data.

Comment: You have two very different questions, which you should consider asking separately.

Comment: Sure, so I'll just ask the one that I really care about.

Comment: I'm glad that's the one you chose. Everything you do in numpy for something this simple is going to be ok, but efficiency is very difficult to demonstrate universally.

Comment: Gotta say, excellent response time and clarity. Very nice to see that from someone calling themselves fairly new.

Comment: Thanks :)
I said I was a beginner in numpy, not in general LOL

Comment: I see. It shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

```
x = (x <= np.median(x, axis=0))
```

The result will be a boolean array of zeros and ones. This wouldn't work, by the way, if you tried it with `axis=1`, because broadcasting matches axes from the right. Instead, you would have to insert a placeholder for the reduced axis, e.g. like this:

```
x = (x <= np.median(x, axis=1)[..., np.newaxis])
```

An even more general approach would be

```
x = (x <= np.median(x, axis=<whatever>, keepdims=True))
```

Since booleans are technically a subclass of integers in Python, and numpy honors that convention, you can get a mask with ones and twos instead of zeros and ones by adding one to the result, however you choose to compute it:

```
x = ... + 1
```

Comment: You can also just add `1` to get the `1`s and `2`s of the original

Comment: I want the data in 1s and 2s, and this returns a 2D boolean array.

Comment: @Ashkan. Updated